# What app.set function does (express.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node.js and was going through an example could not understand app.set('title', 'My Site'); does please help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the express instance to store and retrieve variables. In this case, you can set the title to be "My Site" and retrieve it later with something like

```
var title = app.get('title');
```

without the need to declare and keep a global variable messing around.

The name of the parameter means nothing. You could do

```
app.set('jabberwocky', 'correct battery horse staples');
```

as well. If you're using express with jade, for example, you might need to retrieve the value of 'jabberwocky' in a template, further along the line.

---

**Edit**: Since this answer got marked as correct and it's the most upvoted, It's my duty to point you to the one further below by [Vlad Pana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7864865/vlad-pana) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007538/1030087

Quire a few keynames you set on the app instance do have a special meaning.

Answer (score 7):

I know I am a bit late to the party but I had the same problem and that's how I got here. 
After I did some research, I fell that the answer is a bit incomplete.
In case that first parameter is an application setting, the following table must be read.

Property -> 
Type -> 
Description

case sensitive routing -> 
Boolean  -> 
Enable case sensitivity. When enabled, "/Foo" and "/foo" are different routes. When disabled, "/Foo" and "/foo" are treated the same.

env -> 
String -> 
Environment mode. Be sure to set to "production" in a production environment; see Production best practices: performance and reliability.
process.env.NODE_ENV (NODE_ENV environment variable) or “development” if NODE_ENV is not set.

etag -> 
Varied -> 
Set the ETag response header. For possible values, see the etag options table.

jsonp callback name -> 
String -> 
Specifies the default JSONP callback name.

json replacer -> 
Varied -> 
The 'replacer' argument used by `JSON.stringify`.
NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting.

json spaces -> 
Varied -> 
The 'space' argument used by `JSON.stringify`. This is typically set to the number of spaces to use to indent prettified JSON.
NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting.

query parser -> 
Varied   -> 
Disable query parsing by setting the value to false, or set the query parser to use either “simple” or “extended” or a custom query string parsing function.
The simple query parser is based on Node’s native query parser, querystring.
The extended query parser is based on qs.
A custom query string parsing function will receive the complete query string, and must return an object of query keys and their values.

strict routing -> 
Boolean  -> 
Enable strict routing. When enabled, the router treats "/foo" and "/foo/" as different. Otherwise, the router treats "/foo" and "/foo/" as the same.
NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting.

subdomain offset -> 
Number -> 
The number of dot-separated parts of the host to remove to access subdomain.

trust proxy -> 
Varied   -> 
Indicates the app is behind a front-facing proxy, and to use the X-Forwarded-* headers to determine the connection and the IP address of the client. NOTE: X-Forwarded-* headers are easily spoofed and the detected IP addresses are unreliable.

When enabled, Express attempts to determine the IP address of the client connected through the front-facing proxy, or series of proxies. The `req.ips` property, then contains an array of IP addresses the client is connected through. To enable it, use the values described in the trust proxy options table.

The `trust proxy` setting is implemented using the proxy-addr package. For more information, see its documentation.
NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting, even though it has a default value.

views  -> 
String or Array -> 
A directory or an array of directories for the application's views. If an array, the views are looked up in the order they occur in the array.
process.cwd() + '/views'

view cache -> 
Boolean  -> 
Enables view template compilation caching.

view engine -> 
String -> 
The default engine extension to use when omitted.
NOTE: Sub-apps will inherit the value of this setting.

x-powered-by -> 
Boolean -> 
Enables the "X-Powered-By: Express" HTTP header.

Comment: That's an excellent addition. You're right some settings are not just arbitrary names but have an impact in the app's behavior

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

This will set your apps view folder to something like:

```
/Users/jilles/Project/myApp/views
```